# How to open Whatsapp with "New Broadcast Message" activity on?

Tags: android, android-intent

Does someone know how to form `Intent` so that Whatsapp would open with New Broadcast Message activity on? I would also like to pass in my Intent the message I want to broadcast.

I managed to write the code below:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
String text = getTellFriendText(mActivity);
i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
if (appInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp")) {
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    mActivity.startActivity(i);
    } 
else {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    Toast tost = Toast.makeText(activity, "Whatsapp is not installed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    tost.show();    
     }
    });
}
```

It starts Whatsapp with extra text passed which can be used as message.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way for calling one activity from an another application's activity.

```
if(isAppInstalled("com.example.myproject")){
            final Intent intent = new Intent();

            ComponentName cName = new ComponentName
            ("com.example.myproject","com.example.myproject.MainActivity");

            intent.setComponent(cName);         
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

And

```
protected boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
    Intent mIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (mIntent != null) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.example.package", "com.example.package.ActivityToStart");
startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
Intent intent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.package");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: First part: Ok, I know the package name. But... How do I know third party application activity name? Second part: According to documentation getLaunchIntentForPackage is of no use to me. It just starts a "good" activity.

Comment: com.whatsapp - standard writing method for definig package names is to write web site vise versa.

Comment: I'm sorry, i cant answer on the second part of question, sorry.